# How to handle axios.all request fails

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, axios

How can I handle request fails in this example of axios.all requests. I.e. if all servers are responde with JSON all is okay and I have JSON file at end of a cycle. But if one of this servers not responde with JSON or not responde at all I do have nothing in "/data.json" file, even all other servers are working perfectly. How can I catch a server fail and skip it?

```
var fs = require("fs");
var axios = require('axios');
var util = require('util');
var round = 0;
var tmp = {};

var streem = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/data.json', {flags : 'w'});

toFile = function(d) { //
  streem.write(util.format(d));
};
start();
setInterval(start, 27000);

function start(){
    streem = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/data.json', {flags : 'w'});
    monitor();
}

function monitor(){

    axios.all([
    axios.get('server1:api'),
    axios.get('server2:api'),
    axios.get('server3:api'),
    axios.get('server4:api'),
    ]).then(axios.spread((response1, response2, response3, response4) => {

        tmp.servers = {};
        tmp.servers.server1 = {};
        tmp.servers.server1 = response1.data;

        tmp.servers.server2 = {};
        tmp.servers.server2 = response2.data;

        tmp.servers.server3 = {};
        tmp.servers.server3 = response3.data;

        tmp.servers.server4 = {};
        tmp.servers.server4 = response4.data;

        toFile(JSON.stringify(tmp));

        round++;

        streem.end();
        streem.on('finish', () => {
            console.error('Round: ' + round);
        });             

    })).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Inside of your `then` statement, you need to handle cases when `response.data` does not exist or `response` returns an error code. Do you see a specific error in the console or command line?

Comment: I have nothing in console when one of the servers are not responded, script just stucking.

Answer (score 0):

The most standard way to approach this would be a recursive function like below.

```
let promises = [
    axios.get('server1:api'),
    axios.get('server2:api'),
    axios.get('server3:api'),
    axios.get('server4:api'),
];

async function monitor() {
    const responses = (arguments.length === 1 ? [arguments[0]] : Array.apply(null, arguments))[0];
    const nextPromise = promises.shift();

    if (nextPromise) {
        try {
            const response = await getSentenceFragment(offset);
            responses.push(response);
        }
        catch (error) {
            responses.push({});
        }

        return responses.concat(await monitor(responses));
    } else {
        return responses;
    }
}


monitor([]).then(([response1, response2, response3, response4]) => {
    tmp.servers = {};
    tmp.servers.server1 = {};
    tmp.servers.server1 = response1.data;

    tmp.servers.server2 = {};
    tmp.servers.server2 = response2.data;

    tmp.servers.server3 = {};
    tmp.servers.server3 = response3.data;

    tmp.servers.server4 = {};
    tmp.servers.server4 = response4.data;

    toFile(JSON.stringify(tmp));

    round++;

    streem.end();
    streem.on('finish', () => {
        console.error('Round: ' + round);
    });             
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but node says me: 

`async function monitor() {
        ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`

Comment: What version of node are you running? It should be supported in version 8 and above. The latest version is 10.

Comment: Ok, I install now version 10.1.0 and now athother error:
`at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)
(node:19358) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19358) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code`

Comment: There may be small syntax errors. I did not run the code myself just wanted to show you the gist.

Comment: How can I be shure is this gist or not if it's not working?